# Writing Summary Log and Catching Errors from Script

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and would like an input on the following script. My goal is to essentially output any errors found when running the copy-items for example if a file is not found, I would like to add it to the log, and if it is found then add it to the log. So far I have been successful adding the items found but all the errors are not written to the log file. Finally, I would also like to get a total number of items moved successfully, but I keep getting 0 or 1 no matter where I place "foreach-object {$I++}"

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

```
$CSVFile = "~\Desktop\Report.csv"
$LogFile = New-item -ItemType file -Path "~\Desktop\Output.log"
$FolderA = "~\Desktop\Test1"
$FolderB = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "~\Desktop\Test2"
$CSVColumn = "Objects"
$I = 0 

Import-Csv $CSVFile | ForEach-Object { 

Try {Copy-Item "$FolderA\$($_.$CSVColumn)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $FolderB}

Catch {

Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value "ERROR moving $_."}

Finally {

Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value "File $($_.$CSVColumn) Photos has been sucessfully copied to Destination"} 

} 
ForEach-Object {$I++}

Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value "Total Items Moved: $I"
Write-Host "Script Completed, See Log for Details."
```

Comment: Try changing `Copy-Item "$FolderA\$($_.$CSVColumn)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `Copy-Item "$FolderA\$($_.$CSVColumn)" -ErrorAction Stop`.  This doesn't stop the whole script, but should cause the failed copy action to drop into the `catch`.  The `$i++` should go inside your `try` block, after the copy action - it will increment only if the copy works, since with the previous modification, it will skip that step when it moves to the `catch`.

Comment: Use `-ErrorAction Stop` on Copy-Item to enter the catch block if an exception occurs. Move `$I++` into the `try` block as second line after the Copy-Item line. Then remove `ForEach-Object {$I++}`

Comment: Also, when doing as previous commenters have advised, remove the `finally` block. Typically it is not used with `try/catch` in this manner, as the successful path is already within the `try` block.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked great, is there any way to sort the log between the items that have been successful vs the ones that aren't ? Also when I look at the log for the items that are successful it just gives me the name and custom text. But for the non- successful it gives me the full error string. Can I modify it to only say the "file name has not been moved successfully."